# MSSQL Insert Index as hint

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

currenlty im tinkering around with a bit of mssql and a DB a friend created. All working fine except that one Insert Statement.

Im trying to get Data from an Front-End and put it into the Tables. And am stuck with the following error after tinkering around a bit and failing.

```
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. 
If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required.
```

My insert Statement looks like the following.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SomeID,PointID) VALUES (?,?) WITH Index(?)'
```

The ? are placeholders as im doing this with a Python Lib (PyODBC)

Cheers!

Comment: Specifying and index when inserting like this makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve? i.e. How do you think this statement would differ from simply `INSERT INTO TestTable (SomeID,PointID) VALUES (?,?);`

Comment: The Problem is i need to declare an Index actually as it is not simply counting. so the indexes look atm like 1,2,3,2,3,1 . I also had tried the statement as `INSERT INTO TestTable (SomeID,Index,PointID) VALUES (?,?,?)'` . But this leads to the same error.

Comment: `Index` is a reserved word in SQL Server (and every other DMBS that I know of), so you would need to use `[]` to differentiate your column name `Index` from the key word `Index`, i.e.  `INSERT INTO TestTable (SomeID,[Index],PointID) VALUES (?,?,?)`. It is generally a good idea to avoid naming any objects with reserved words or special characters, as it leads to issues exactly like this.

Comment: @GarethD that was the error thanks :) mind posting this as answer so i can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Index` is a reserved word in SQL Server (and every other DMBS that I know of), so you would need to use `[]` to differentiate your column name Index from the key word Index, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SomeID,[Index],PointID) VALUES (?,?,?).
```

It is generally a good idea to avoid naming any objects with reserved words or special characters, as it leads to issues exactly like this.